# Mysql SELECT with LIKE clause returns result set containing NOT LIKE fields

Tags: mysql

I am running a query against a mysql database:

```
SELECT * FROM cdt_LearningActivityClientLang WHERE preparation LIKE '%&nbsp;&nbsp;%';
```

This returns a result set with records that do not match the `LIKE` clause.
An example of the `preparation` field within one of these unwanted records is:

```
'<ol><li>Print race track sheet on cardstock (1 for each
group).&nbsp;</li><li>Print VC &amp; CVC sentence cards on cardstock
(1 set for each group).</li><li>Cut out VC &amp; CVC sentence cards.
Laminate, if possible.</li><li>Locate game pieces (1 for each
child).</li><li>Locate die (1 for each group).</li></ol>'
```

As you can see this field contains a single `&nbsp;`. Why is the `LIKE` returning this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK the above record should _not_ be getting returned.  Are you certain that you are reporting correctly here?

Comment: You are right.. I had an older DB dump being queried on my second tab of mysql workbench. My bad haha, thanks anyway though.